# Simple: How to initialize a new unordered_map<std::string,std::string>* (pointer) in C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

```
unordered_map<std::string, std::string>* Accounts;
```

I have this code up there to initialize from a pointer, I could just leave the pointer( * ) out of it and I could directly assign the value into it, but the problem is that I'm using C++/Cli on Visual Studio 2008 and I can't define a variable there in the class scope

because it throws this error:

> error C4368: cannot define 'Accounts' as a member of managed
>   'Test::Login': mixed types are not
>   supported C:\
>   Projects\Test\Login.h 32

So I was told that I should make a pointer and then initialize it in the constructor, but how do I create it from the pointer ? (I thought something like Accounts = new unordered_map)
I use to always go directly.

I hope I was clear enough.

**@edit**

```
public ref class Login: public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:

        unordered_map< std::string, std::string >* Accounts;

        Test(void)
        {
            this->Accounts = new unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
        this->Accounts["hello"] = "test";
                    cout << this->Accounts["hello"];
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //

        }
```

it throws this error:

> Error 4   error C2107: illegal index, indirection not
>   allowed   C:\Projects\Test
>   Login.h   37

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Accounts = new unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;` didn't work or what?

Comment: `new std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>()` ?

Comment: I put an @edit and shew the error its happening when trying to set a value in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unordered_map<std::string, std::string>* Accounts = new unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
```

Just remember you need to delete it when you are done.

```
delete Accounts;
```

Comment: And that you need to make your class noncopyable or add proper copy semantics (and move in C++11).

Comment: I put an @edit and shew the error its happening when trying to set a value in it.